# SQL update value to be the sum of a selection of products

Tags: mysql, sql

I have order_items with an order_id, quantity, and a unit_price

I want my orders, total_price column to equal the sum of all associated order_items quantity multiplied by the unit_price

This is my failing SQL-statement:

```
update orders set total_price=SUM(select quantity*unit_price from order_items where orders_id=?) where id=?
```

Table structure:

### `orders`:

`id`;

`total_price`;

### `order_items`:

`order_id` (references order(id));

`quantity`;

`unit_price`;

**How can I execute this operation through SQL?**

Answer (score 3):

Just move the `sum()` inside the subquery:

```
update orders o 
    set total_price = (select sum(quantity*unit_price) from order_items where orders_id=?)
    where id=?;
```

Note:  by using a correlated subquery, you can do this with just one parameter:

```
update orders o 
    set total_price = (select sum(oi.quantity * oi.unit_price)
                       from order_items oi
                       where oi.orders_id = o.id
                      )
    where id=?;
```